# Using Green's theorem to calculate the area bounded by half of a cycloid

Tags: calculus, vector-analysis, greens-theorem

> The area bounded by half of a cycloid $\alpha(t)=(R(t-\sin(t), R(1-\cos(t))$ where $R>0$ and $0 \leq t \leq \pi$ and the x-axis is:

I've tried to use Green's theorem to solve this, by "closing" the original curve, creating two curves $\mathcal{C}_2$ and $\mathcal{C}_3$ (the red one and the blue one respectively). They're all clockwise oriented.

[image]

The parametric equations for both curves are:

$\begin{cases}\alpha_2(t)=(\pi R, t) \\ \alpha _2:[0,2R] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \end{cases}$

and

$\begin{cases}\alpha_3(t)=(t, 0) \\ \alpha _3:[0,\pi R] \to \mathbb{R}^2 \end{cases}$

And the vector field $F:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ $F(x,y)=(0,x)$ such that the curl of $F$ is (0,0,1).

So by Green's theorem, using $\mathcal{C}'=\underbrace{\mathcal{C}_1}_{\text{Original curve}} \cup \mathcal{C}_2 \cup \mathcal{C}_3$:

$\oint\limits_{\mathcal{C}'} F dl = \iint\limits_{D} dx dy = A(D)$

Where D is the surface bounded by the curve $\mathcal{C}'$.

$A(D)=\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_1}F dl-\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_2}F dl-\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_3}F dl$ (negative signs to change the orientation of the curves).

$\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_1}F dl=\int\limits_{0} ^{\pi} R^2(t-\sin t)\sin t dt = \frac{\pi R^2}{2}$

$\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_2}F dl=\int\limits_{0} ^{2R} \pi R dt = 2 \pi R^2$

$\int\limits_{\mathcal{C}_3}F dl=\int\limits_{0} ^{\pi R} 0 dt = 0 $

So, I end up with

$$
A(D)=\frac{-3 \pi R^2}{2}
$$

Why am I getting a negative area? Is this correct?

Comment: Possibly because you need the reverse orientation. When you travel along the boundary, the region should be on your left side.

Comment: @uniquesolution that makes sense! I never took into account the orientation of C' as a whole, just thought that I had to use the original curve's orientation. Thank you so much!